# Getting mysql error while trying to post data from db to a webpage

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to show values from DB onto a web page. Here is the code below.

```
//connect db

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mylearndb') OR die('Cannot connect because: '.mysqli_connect_error());

//Run query...

$q = "SELECT * FROM 'pages' WHERE id = 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
```

In the index page, I am trying to print the results in a table:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Customer ID</td>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td>Email ID</td>
        <td>Phone no</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $page['cust_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page['email_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page['phone_no']; ?></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

When I go and check the page, it throws the error...

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..

The above code runs in a file called `setup.php` and I call that file into `index.php`.

Comment: know when to use single quotes and backticks `'pages'`

Comment: also use `mysqli_error()` function together with any call to your database, including your`mysqli_query()` row.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this error indicates a problem with your query.

Remove quote(') from table name in query.

Write query as follows:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if(!$r)
   die("Mysql Query Error"); 
$page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
```